# Android development - GPS not working - Application hangs when co-ordinates sent

Tags: android-emulator, gps

**Problem Background**:

I am somewhat new to Android development. All I'm trying to do, for now, is to get GPS coordinates from the GPS device of the phone and display them on Google Maps or just in a `TextView`, or whatever. The main task is to get them.

I've read a number of tutorials. I'm using
- Android 2.3.3
- API level 10
- Eclipse 3.6.1
- Windows 7

---

**Problem Description** :

I have written a class `GeoUpdateHandler` which implements `LocationListener` and implements its methods `onLocationChange()` etc. And in `MyMapsActivity`, I use the regular `requestLocationUpdates` of the `LocationManager` to get periodic updates.

When I run the application, I send GPS coordinates from the Emulator Control of Eclipse (Window --> Show View --> Other --> Android --> Emulator Control) to send Longitude and Latitude. As soon as the emulated device gets the coordinates, the application hangs. Nothing happens and the cursor changes to the blue circle (which signifies thinking/stuck) and nothing happens. If I use `locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(String provider)`, it gets null. Obviously, because there IS no last known location. It gets stuck before knowing one!

I have tried sending the coordinates through telnet as well. (cmd --> telnet localhost 5554 --> geo fix  . But the same thing happens.

I have tried starting the device independent of the application, sending the coordinates, and then starting the application. But the same thing happens when I run the application: it hangs.

The following code `HelloItemizedOverlay` is taken from Android's MapView tutorial and works fine with manually given coordinates. The problem arises when GPS location is tried to be retrieved.

```
public class MyMapsActivity extends MapActivity 
{
private MapController mapController;
private MapView mapView;
private LocationManager locationManager;
LinearLayout linLayout;
MapView mView;
List<Overlay> mapOverlays;
Drawable drawable;
HelloItemizedOverlay itemizedOverlay;
GeoUpdateHandler handler;
Location location;
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main); // bind the layout to the activity

    mView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mapOverlays = mView.getOverlays();
    drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon);
    itemizedOverlay = new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable);

    mapController = mView.getController();
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    handler = new GeoUpdateHandler();
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 3000, 0, handler);

    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int)location.getLongitude(),(int)location.getLatitude());
    OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, "", "");

    mView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);

    mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);

    mapController.setZoom(8);
    mapController.animateTo(point);
}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() 
{
    return false;
}

public class GeoUpdateHandler implements LocationListener 
{
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) 
    {
        int lat = (int) (location.getLatitude());
        int lng = (int) (location.getLongitude());
        GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(lat, lng);
        mapController.animateTo(point); //  mapController.setCenter(point);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) 
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) 
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) 
    {

    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    handler = new GeoUpdateHandler();
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 0, handler);
    super.onResume();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/GeoPoint.html), the `Geopoint` constructor takes (latitude * 1e6, longitude * 1e6) as parameters ; whereas you put (longitude, latitude) when calling `getLastKnownLocation`, and you forgot the scale factor in the other call (in `onLocationChanged`). Latitude and logitude are not scaled in [Location](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getLatitude%28%29) objects.

Anyways, this error should only result in displaying a blue map ((0,0) being in the atlantic ocean), so there may be other problems.

---

Edit:

1/ in replay to your comment, if you mix up longitude and latitude, you may get an unexisting point (latitude always stays within [-90°,90°] whereas longitude can vary in [-180°,180°])

2/ there is a bug in SDK 2.3 (API level 9), which makes the emulator crash when sending mock locations. Don't know wether it is true for 2.3.3 (lvl 10), but I used 2.1u1 (lvl 7) to test.

3/ The following code works for me :

```
package test.testmap;

import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;

public class MyMapsActivity extends MapActivity 
{
    private MapController mapController;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    LinearLayout linLayout;
    MapView mView;
    List<Overlay> mapOverlays;
    Drawable drawable;
    HelloItemizedOverlay itemizedOverlay;
    GeoUpdateHandler handler;
    Location location;
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main); // bind the layout to the activity

        drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon);
        itemizedOverlay = new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable);

        mView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        mapOverlays = mView.getOverlays();
        mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);

        mapController = mView.getController();
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() 
    {
        return false;
    }

    public class GeoUpdateHandler implements LocationListener 
    {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) 
        {
            Log.d(this.getClass().getName(),"onLocationChanged : lat = "+location.getLatitude()+" lon = "+location.getLongitude());
            int lat = (int) Math.round(location.getLatitude()*1.0e6);
            int lng = (int) Math.round(location.getLongitude()*1.0e6);
            GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(lat, lng);
            itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(new OverlayItem(point, "", ""));
            mapController.animateTo(point);
            mapController.setZoom(8);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) 
        {
            Log.d(this.getClass().getName(),"onProviderDisabled");
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) 
        {
            Log.d(this.getClass().getName(),"onProviderEnabled");
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) 
        {
            Log.d(this.getClass().getName(),"onStatusChanged");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        handler = new GeoUpdateHandler();
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 0, handler);
        super.onResume();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Stéphane! But giving (longitude, latitude) in place of (latitude, longitude) should just become a different locatoin from the one I want it to be. And yeah, the scaling thing matters. But don't know why when I manually make a Geopoint by giving sample latitude and longitude values, it does show it on the map.
But thanks anyway. :)
There has to be a more serious problem. Either in my code, which I now find very unlikely, or in the emulator or something else.

Comment: Can you log the lat/lon values you get (straight out of the Location object)? Well I don't have much time right now, but hopefully I'll have a closer look later today (time zone GMT+1)...